# How to create Grouped UItableview  Alphabetically

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview

I am working in an app in which I have an array and using that array that comes as response from JSON in the table view .Now In table view I want Sections in which i get the value from  the array Alphabetically.For say if the Array element starts with A then it should go on A section and similar for all other alphabets from A to Z. How can i do this?

Comment: Its similar to the contact list shown in iPhone. You must divide the table into sections.